# Disk usage for a mounted drive shows up completely between the host and a container

Tags: disk-usage, docker, lxc, openvz, container

When comparing the disk usage for a mounted harddrive the usage is completely different when compared between the host and the container.
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on the host and in the lxc container.

The hard drive is mounted on the host as confirmed by `/etc/mtab` which has the following entry: `/dev/nvme0n1 /mnt/SSD ext4 rw 0 0`. The drive however is not mounted using `/etc/fstab`.
The drive is mounted inside the lxc container using fstab settings in: `/var/lib/lxc/container_name/fstab`.

From the host:

```
# du -hs /mnt/SSD/
20K     /mnt/SSD/

# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        63G  4.0K   63G   1% /dev
tmpfs                       13G  1.4M   13G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/sifr--vg-root  314G  241G   58G  81% /
none                       4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        63G     0   63G   0% /run/shm
none                       100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                  236M  100M  124M  45% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1               1.1T   71M  1.1T   1% /mnt/SSD
```

From the container

```
$ du -hs /mnt/SSD/
16G /mnt/SSD/

$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/sifr--vg-root  314G  241G   58G  81% /
none                       4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                        13G  136K   13G   1% /run
none                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        63G  4.0K   63G   1% /run/shm
none                       100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

1. How and why does the same drive shows two different usages?
2. Which is the correct usage?

**Update:**
After unmounting the drive using `sudo umount /dev/nvme0n1`, I now see 16GB disk usage in the host and the container:

```
$ du -hs /mnt/SSD/
16G     /mnt/SSD/
```

I mounted another drive `/dev/sdb` using `/etc/fstab` and gave the container access to it using the same method: `/var/lib/lxc/container_name/fstab`. The second drive's usage is also consistent and the contents are available in both the container and the host.

The differences between the two drives are that `/dev/nvme0n1` is a nvme drive which was mounted manually, whereas `/dev/sdb` is a magnetic drive and was mounted using `/etc/fstab`.

What could be causing the difference in the behaviour and how to make `/dev/nvme0n1` available in the container?

Comment: /mnt/SSD which container sees don't have to be /mnt/SSD that host sees, because of mount namespaces isolation. That's how privateTmp on systemd works. Check mounts for particular cgroup-ed process .

Comment: @BobanP. Thanks for responding. How can I check mounts for cgroup-ed processes? 

I've updated the post: once the drive was unmounted the disk usage was consistent in both the container and how. It looks like the container was not using the drive. I mounted another drive using `/etc/fstab` and it works fine. 

Not sure if mouting it manually vs through fstab could cause this behaviour?

Comment: try systemd-cgls, and then when you find PID of process i cgroup, cat /proc/[PID]/mountinfo